# Simple SQL Express Full Join Query does not return nulls when it should

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

Here is the query:

```
SELECT        
    AttributeName.ID, Attributes.LinkAnalyses, Attributes.Value, AttributeName.Name
FROM            
    AttributeName 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    Attributes ON AttributeName.ID = Attributes.LinkName
```

I should be getting nulls returned because LinkAnalyses = 88 only has linknames up to 10 where attributename has linknames up to 21. I should get 11 nulls but I get none

Output:

[image]

Attributes table:

[image]

AttributeName table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Full join will work based on joining key you are used in your query.

In your query, you use AttributeName.ID = Attributes.LinkName, So if any ID from AttributeName is missing in LinkName column in table Attributes (and vice versa) will return null row.

There have no relation in your column Attributes.LinkAnalysis.

If you want LinkAnalysis wise full join , you can use below query

```
select 
Id,Attributes.LinkAnalyses,Value,Name
from 
( SELECT  
 an.LinkAnalyses,AttributeName.ID,AttributeName.Name
 FROM            
 (Select distinct LinkAnalyses from Attributes ) an
  ,  AttributeName 
) A
full join Attributes on Attributes.LinkAnalyses=A.LinkAnalyses and A.ID =Attributes.LinkName
```

Comment: AttributeName.ID is used as a link to Attributes.LinkAnalyses .The query above yields : Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'LinkAnalysis'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'ID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'Name'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'LinkAnalysis'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'LinkName'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'Id'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'LinkAnalysis'.
- Could not fit all errors

Comment: Its a typo.. You can check the query now.